# Loop to count workdays until received

Tags: excel, vba

If (C) received date is greater than 1, then count workdays between (A) order and (C) received dates, if not, then count workdays from (A) order date until today (today or now).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Trying to count workdays until received, stopping with the total days needed once the received date is entered. This is for a long list of records (rows).

a2 (order date), b2 (the count), c2(received date)

I tried setting the received date as rd >1 boolean:

```vb
sub count()

    dim rd as boolean

    if range("c2").value +>1 then
        rd = true
    else
        rd = false

        if rd = true then
           range("b2").value = worksheetfunction.networkdays(range("a2"), range("c2"))
        end if
    end if
end sub
```

1. How to use the holiday list on the worksheet second tab in the workday third position.
2. How to loop.
3. How to make a second function if rd was false.
4. I could only get it to count from a2 if I used dim ws as worksheet (table1) and so on.

Answer (score 1):

[Holidays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays) - The list can be either a range of cells that contains the dates or an array constant of the serial numbers that represent the dates.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub wdcount()

   Dim lastrow As Long, f As String
   
   ' count formula R1C1 notation
   f = "=NetworkDays(RC[-1],IF(RC[1]>0,RC[1],Today()),table2!R2C3:R11C3)"

   'Debug.Print f
   With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table1")
       lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
       .Range("B2:B" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = f
   End With

End Sub
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252367/discussion-on-answer-by-cdp1802-excel-vba-loop-trying-to-count-workdays-until-r); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The VBA gods came up with a solution!

This works!

```vb
-------------------------------------------
Option Explicit

Sub wdcount()

    Dim lastrow As Long, f As String
    
    Debug.Print f
    
    f = "=NetworkDays(RC[-1],IF(RC[1]>0,RC[1],Today()),table2!R2C3:R11C3)"
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("table1")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("B2:B" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = f
        
    End With
    
End Sub
' Took a while to figure out. 
'The counting column is considered [R0] but is listed at the bottom as "S3:S" for the entire column.
' then the start date is the first [R] and is a negative number to the left and a positive to the right, counting columns.(start date on A but counting on D would be [R-3] for example.)
' the end date is calculated the same as the start date by counting columns. Important to make sure both following [r]s are the same.
-------------------------------------------------
'worksheet tab "table1"
     'Column A start date, B the count, C the end date.
'worksheet tab "table2"
     'Column C2 to C11 holiday dates 
     '(not counted in the workdays m-f)
```

Comment: This worked for rows A B C but how do you get it to use other rows? For example, on a second counting area, the start date is "N", count "Q", and the receiving date "R".